# Angular routing kind of not working with Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a Nginx app with an Angular project uploaded on it. Whenever I refresh on an Angular route, it says "404 Not Found".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the angular routing acts only on the client side. You have to configure your webserver to always point to index.html

Sample for nginx:

```
location / {
    root   html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```